# User input creates errors if more than 1 word input in simple Java app with MySql database

Tags: java, mysql, java.util.scanner

I am just learning SQL and this is my first task to incorporate it into a Java app. I am having issues with multiple words input by the user and it's breaking. If I only type on word with no spaces everything works fine. I would really appreciate some help!

Here are some **screenshots** of the **errors** (It may have to do with the scanner, but for the life of me I cannot fix it!) The code is below.

[If I type in 2 words, displays the following 2 the .next() together.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3wGQ.png)

[But if I only type 1 word it doesn't break.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysyyz.png)

[The same for 'searching' by title, if I type in more than one word the following error occurs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUw82.png)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.*;

// This is a simple bookstore application that allows the user to add, update, 
// delete and search for books in the MySQL database.

// Book class
class Books {
    public int id;
    public String title;
    public String author;
    public int qty;
    public String search;

    public Books() {
    }

    public Books(int id, String title, String author, int qty) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.qty = qty;
    }
}


// BookStore Class
public class BookStore {
    public int choice;
    static int id = 0;
    static String title = "";
    static String author = "";
    static int qty = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        boolean quit = false;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int menu = 0;
        
        System.out.println("Betty's Book Store\n-----------------------------");

        // SQL details
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebookstore_db?useSSL=false";
        String user = "otheruser";
        String password = "swordfish";
        
        PreparedStatement myStmt = null;
        Connection myConn = null;

        do {
            // Menu
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("1. Enter book");
            System.out.println("2. Update book");
            System.out.println("3. Delete book");
            System.out.println("4. Search books");
            System.out.println("5. Exit");

            System.out.print("\nPlease enter your choice: ");
            menu = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            switch (menu) {

            case 1:
                System.out.println("1. Enter book\n-----------------------------");

                try {
                    // Add a new book
                    System.out.print("Book ID: ");
                    int id = input.nextInt();

                    System.out.print("Book Title: ");
                    String title = input.next();

                    System.out.print("Book Author: ");
                    String author = input.next();

                    System.out.print("Quantity: ");
                    int qty = input.nextInt();

                    // 1. Get a connection to database
                    myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

                    // 2. Create a statement
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO books " + " (id, title, author, qty)" + " values (?, ?, ?, ?)";

                    myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

                    // Set parameter values
                    myStmt.setInt(1, id);
                    myStmt.setString(2, title);
                    myStmt.setString(3, author);
                    myStmt.setInt(4, qty);

                    // 3. Execute SQL query
                    myStmt.executeUpdate();

                    System.out.println("Insert complete.");
                    printAllFromTable(myStmt);

                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();

                } finally {
                    if (myStmt != null) {
                        myStmt.close();
                    }

                    if (myConn != null) {
                        myConn.close();
                    }
                }

                break;

            case 2:
                // Update a book's data
                System.out.println("2. Update book\n-----------------------------");

                try {
                    // Search for book by ID
                    System.out.print("Enter Book ID: ");
                    int searchId = input.nextInt();
                    int id = searchId;
                    ResultSet results;

                    // 1. Get a connection to database
                    myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

                    // 2. Create a statement
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = ?";
                    myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

                    // Set parameter values
                    myStmt.setInt(1, id);

                    // Set parameter values
                    myStmt.setInt(1, id);

                    // 3. Execute SQL query
                    results = myStmt.executeQuery();

                    // Loop over the results, printing them all.
                    while (results.next()) {
                        System.out.println(results.getInt("id") + ", " + results.getString("title") + ", "
                                + results.getString("author") + ", " + results.getInt("qty") + "\n");
                    }

                    // Close up our connections
                    results.close();

                    // Sub menu for updating book data after selecting ID
                    System.out.println("1. Update ID");
                    System.out.println("2. Update Title");
                    System.out.println("3. Update Author");
                    System.out.println("4. Update Quantity");
                    System.out.println("5. Main menu");

                    do {
                        System.out.print("\nPlease enter your choice: ");
                        menu = input.nextInt();
                        System.out.println();
                        switch (menu) {

                        case 1:
                            try {
                                // Update Book ID
                                System.out.print("Enter New ID: ");
                                int updateId = input.nextInt();
                                int id2 = updateId;

                                // 1. Get a connection to database
                                myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

                                // 2. Create a statement
                                String sql1 = "UPDATE books SET id = ? WHERE id = ?";
                                myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql1);

                                // Set parameter values
                                myStmt.setInt(1, id2);
                                myStmt.setInt(2, id);

                                // 3. Execute SQL query
                                myStmt.execute();

                                System.out.println("ID updated.");
                                printAllFromTable(myStmt);

                            } catch (Exception exc) {
                                exc.printStackTrace();

                            } finally {
                                if (myStmt != null) {
                                    myStmt.close();
                                }

                                if (myConn != null) {
                                    myConn.close();
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            try {
                                // Update Book title
                                System.out.print("Enter New Title: ");
                                String title = input.next();

                                // 1. Get a connection to database
                                myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

                                // 2. Create a statement
                                String sql1 = "UPDATE books SET title = ? WHERE id = ?";
                                myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql1);

                                // Set parameter values
                                myStmt.setString(1, title);
                                myStmt.setInt(2, id);

                                // 3. Execute SQL query
                                myStmt.execute();

                                System.out.println("Title updated.");
                                printAllFromTable(myStmt);

                            } catch (Exception exc) {
                                exc.printStackTrace();

                            } finally {
                                if (myStmt != null) {
                                    myStmt.close();
                                }

                                if (myConn != null) {
                                    myConn.close();
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            try {
                                // Update Book Author
                                System.out.print("Enter New Author: ");
                                String author = input.next();

                                // 1. Get a connection to database
                                myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

                                // 2. Create a statement
                                String sql1 = "UPDATE books SET author = ? WHERE id = ?";
                                myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql1);

                                // Set parameter values
                                myStmt.setString(1, author);
                                myStmt.setInt(2, id);

                                // 3. Execute SQL query
                                myStmt.execute();

                                System.out.println("Autor updated.");
                                printAllFromTable(myStmt);

                            } catch (Exception exc) {
                                exc.printStackTrace();

                            } finally {
                                if (myStmt != null) {
                                    myStmt.close();
                                }

                                if (myConn != null) {
                                    myConn.close();
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            try {
                                // Update Book Quantity
                                System.out.print("Enter New Quantity: ");
                                int qty = input.nextInt();

                                // 1. Get a connection to database
                                myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

                                // 2. Create a statement
                                String sql1 = "UPDATE books SET qty = ? WHERE id = ?";
                                myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql1);

                                // Set parameter values
                                myStmt.setInt(1, qty);
                                myStmt.setInt(2, id);

                                // 3. Execute SQL query
                                myStmt.execute();

                                System.out.println("Quantity updated.");
                                printAllFromTable(myStmt);

                            } catch (Exception exc) {
                                exc.printStackTrace();

                            } finally {
                                if (myStmt != null) {
                                    myStmt.close();
                                }

                                if (myConn != null) {
                                    myConn.close();
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case 5:
                            break;

                        default:
                            System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
                        }

                    } while (menu != 5);

                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();

                } finally {
                    if (myStmt != null) {
                        myStmt.close();
                    }

                    if (myConn != null) {
                        myConn.close();
                    }
                }

                break;

            case 3:
                // Delete a book from the database
                System.out.println("3. Delete book\n-----------------------------");
                try {
                    // Search
                    System.out.print("Enter Book ID to delete: ");
                    int searchId = input.nextInt();
                    int id = searchId;
                    // 1. Get a connection to database
                    myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

                    // 2. Create a statement
                    String sql = "DELETE FROM books WHERE id = ?";
                    myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

                    // Set parameter values
                    myStmt.setInt(1, id);

                    // 3. Execute SQL query
                    myStmt.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("Delete complete.\n");

//                  printAllFromTable(myStmt);

                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();

                } finally {
                    if (myStmt != null) {
                        myStmt.close();
                    }

                    if (myConn != null) {
                        myConn.close();
                    }
                }

                break;

            case 4:
                // Search for a book in the database
                System.out.println("4. Search books\n-----------------------------");
                System.out.println();

                do {
                    // Sub menu for searching by ID, title or author
                    System.out.println("1. Enter ID");
                    System.out.println("2. Enter Title");
                    System.out.println("3. Enter Author");
                    System.out.println("4. Main menu");
                    System.out.print("\nPlease enter your choice: ");
                    menu = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println();
                    switch (menu) {

                    case 1:
                        try {
                            // Search by book id
                            System.out.print("Enter Book ID: ");
                            int searchId = input.nextInt();
                            int id = searchId;
                            ResultSet results;

                            // 1. Get a connection to database
                            myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

                            // 2. Create a statement
                            String sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = ?";
                            myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

                            // Set parameter values
                            myStmt.setInt(1, id);

                            // 3. Execute SQL query
                            results = myStmt.executeQuery();

                            // Loop over the results, printing them all.
                            while (results.next()) {
                                System.out.println(results.getInt("id") + ", " + results.getString("title") + ", "
                                        + results.getString("author") + ", " + results.getInt("qty"));
                            }

                        } catch (Exception exc) {
                            exc.printStackTrace();

                        } finally {
                            if (myStmt != null) {
                                myStmt.close();
                            }

                            if (myConn != null) {
                                myConn.close();
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        try {
                            // Search by book title
                            System.out.print("Enter Book Title: ");
                            String searchTitle = input.next();
                            String title = searchTitle;
                            ResultSet results;

                            // 1. Get a connection to database
                            myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

                            // 2. Create a statement
                            String sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE title = ?";
                            myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

                            // Set parameter values
                            myStmt.setString(1, title);

                            // 3. Execute SQL query
                            results = myStmt.executeQuery();

                            // Loop over the results, printing them all.
                            while (results.next()) {
                                System.out.println(results.getInt("id") + ", " + results.getString("title") + ", "
                                        + results.getString("author") + ", " + results.getInt("qty"));
                            }

                        } catch (Exception exc) {
                            exc.printStackTrace();

                        } finally {
                            if (myStmt != null) {
                                myStmt.close();
                            }

                            if (myConn != null) {
                                myConn.close();
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        try {
                            // Search by book Author
                            System.out.print("Enter Author: ");
                            String searchAuthor = input.next();
                            String title = searchAuthor;
                            ResultSet results;

                            // 1. Get a connection to database
                            myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

                            // 2. Create a statement
                            String sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE author = ?";
                            myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

                            // Set parameter values
                            myStmt.setString(1, title);

                            // 3. Execute SQL query
                            results = myStmt.executeQuery();

                            // Loop over the results, printing them all.
                            while (results.next()) {
                                System.out.println(results.getInt("id") + ", " + results.getString("title") + ", "
                                        + results.getString("author") + ", " + results.getInt("qty"));
                            }

                        } catch (Exception exc) {
                            exc.printStackTrace();

                        } finally {
                            if (myStmt != null) {
                                myStmt.close();
                            }

                            if (myConn != null) {
                                myConn.close();
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
                    }

                } while (menu != 4);
                break;

            case 5:
                // Exits the program
                System.out.println("Exiting...");
                quit = true;
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
            }
        } while (!quit);

        if (input != null) {
            input.close();
        }

    }
    
    /**
     * Method printing all values in all rows. Takes a statement to try to avoid
     * spreading DB access too far.
     * 
     * @param a statement on an existing connection
     * @throws SQLException
     */

    public static void printAllFromTable(Statement statement) throws SQLException {

        ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT id, title, author, qty FROM books");
        while (results.next()) {
            System.out.println(results.getInt("id") + ", " + results.getString("title") + ", "
                    + results.getString("author") + ", " + results.getInt("qty"));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: [`Scanner#next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) - "_Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern._" So `next()` will read until the next delimiter is found, which in this case is a whitespace (default). You could use `nextLine()` to read the whole line (delimiter then is `\n`). But then you have to watch out for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo.

Comment: What I would do is, take **every** input via `nextLine()` and then parse the input as needed. Then you can enter every item and confirm it by pressing enter.

Comment: you should really look into re-using code, instead of duplicating it x times.

Comment: @maloomeister Thanks I used the page you linked to to solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo